# Objectify - save order of Ref<?>-s

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I have a system where I'm trying to minimize the number of Datastore writes (who wouldn't?), all the while using ancestor relations. Consider the following simplified classes:

```
public class Ancestor {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String field;
    private Ref<Descendant> descendantRef;
    public Descendant getDescendant() {
        return this.descendantRef.get();
    }
    public void setDescendant(Descendant des) {
        this.descendantRef = Ref.create(des);
    }
}

public class Descendant {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String field;
    @Parent
    private Key parent;
}
```

My problem: even though I set the descendant ref, upon saving the Ancestor entity, a `null` is saved, but if I save the Descendant as well, Objectify complains `Attempted to save a null entity`.

My question: I gathered that Objectify optimizes the order of `get()` operations with the `@Load` annotation, so is there a way to make it do the same on `save()` operations as well, so that by the time the Ancestor is being sent to the Datastore, the Descendant ref is populated properly?

Thank you in advance for any advice!

Comment: Are you asking how save() operation for descendantRef can be optimized when you are saving many Ancestor?

Comment: @Ajeet More like if there's a way to call `save()` on the Ancestor only, and have Objectify optimize the "save graph" similar to the load graph and save Descendant first, construct the Ref<>, and save Ancestor with that. This is most likely impossible.
Other than that, if there's a way to construct a descendantRef automatically, in time for the Ancestor to be saved with the ref...

Answer (score 0):

You can hide this implementation like this:

```
public Descendant getDescendant() {
    // You probably don't want to break your code on null descendantRef
    if (this.descendantRef != null) {
        return this.descendantRef.get();
    }
    return null;
}

public void setDescendant(Descendant des) {
    // Insert if this des have never been insert
    if (getDescendant() != null) {
        new DescendantEndpoint().insert(des);
    }
    // You probably don't want to break your code on null des
    if (des != null) {
        this.descendantRef = Ref.create(des);
    }
}
```

By this, you don't have to do deal with each insertion of the ref on each endpoint you will make. Still, this method is not optimized for bulk insert as it will insert on each seperate datastore connection.

For this you can do something like this:

```
private Object bulkInsertAncestor(ArrayList<Ancestor> list){
        ArrayList<Descendant> descendantArrayList = //get descendant list
        // You should do all this inside a transaction
        new DescendantEndpoint().bulkInsertDescendant(descendantArrayList);
        return ofy().save().entities(list);
    }
```

Comment: Also, make sure in your app engine application you have only one insert and bulkInsert API for your each Entity Endpoint

Comment: Let me know if you have any query or doubts. I am working on an application using objectify and app-engine. I am trying my own methods.

Answer (score 0):

Objectify only complains that you `Attempted to save a null entity` if you literally pass a `null` value to the save() method.

This isn't an order-of-operations issue. FWIW, neither Objectify nor the underlying datastore provides any kind of referential integrity checks. It does not matter which you save first.